# surface fitting with least square

Tags: discrete-mathematics, matlab, surfaces, least-squares, discrete-geometry

I want to fit a polynomial surface to some 3d points. 
First in a loop, matrix R is calculated as follows:

```
for j=1:size(indices,1)
            A(j,1:3)=Temp.Location(indices(j),:);
            X = Temp.Location(indices(j),1);
            Y = Temp.Location(indices(j),2);
            R(j, 1) = X*X;
            R(j, 2) = Y*Y;
            R(j, 3) = Y;
            R(j, 4) = X;
            R(j, 5) = X*Y;
            R(j, 6) = 1;
            Z(j, 1) = Temp.Location(indices(j),3);
        end
```

And then  coeficients are calculated as follows:

```
 Cof=inv(R'*R)*R'*Z;
```

The results (z and predicted z) are as follows:
[image]
enter image description here
[image]

[image]
Is the method wrong?
How least square is used as surface fitiing?
Thanks

points: [ x ,y ,z ,predicted z]
[[image]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBBRA.jpg)

Comment: Can you edit the data ( on numeric table, not equations, not graph).

Comment: @JJacquelin. I was about to ask the same ! Cheers.

Comment: @JJacquelin sorry i didn't understand what you mean

Comment: I mean : On your graph you plotted some points. Can you edit the numerical coordinates of the points?

Comment: @JJacquelin Actually I want to fit a surface around a point, So i extracted neighborhood points. I plot all points that are used for least square.

Comment: @JJacquelin you mean I write x y z of them?

Comment: Yes, use the button "Edit" below your question and publish the numeric table of (x,y,z) of all points.

Comment: @JJacquelin it's done but resolution is low

Comment: What they mean is you should do this: at the end of your code, write 
$$ $$
`[X(:); Y(:), Z(:)]` 
$$ $$
That'll cause a list of xyz-triples to be printed to your screen. Then copy that list of triples (using the "{}" button to format it as code, so that it appears as a nice table!) so that we can all see the original data.

Comment: @JohnHughes I wanted to add as code, but the numbers were showed wrong

Comment: Please: not a photo of the original data ... the data itself. A long list of numbers, not pixels. That way, we can copy them and do the matlab ourselves without having to re-type everything.

Comment: There is a function called fit https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html ...I am supremely confused by the mess you have.

Answer (score 1):

NOT AN ANSWER.

This isn't an answer to your question, but it's a cleanup of your code, because ... because it was needed.

You wrote:

```
for j=1:size(indices,1)
        A(j,1:3)=Temp.Location(indices(j),:);
        X = Temp.Location(indices(j),1);
        Y = Temp.Location(indices(j),2);
        R(j, 1) = X*X;
        R(j, 2) = Y*Y;
        R(j, 3) = Y;
        R(j, 4) = X;
        R(j, 5) = X*Y;
        R(j, 6) = 1;
        Z(j, 1) = Temp.Location(indices(j),3);
    end
```

In doing this, you're re-allocating the matrix $R$ each time through the loop. No big deal for 40 points, but a total mess when there are 100000 points.  So let's just fix that a bit by allocating $R$ in advance:

```
n = size(indices, 1);
R = zeros(n, 6);

for j=1:n
    ... 
end
```

Now let's get more idomatic: when you want to extract items 1, 2, 3 of an array, you can write

```
for j = 1:3
  U(j) = X(j)
end
```

or you can just write

U([1 2 3]) = X([1 2 3])

which is the more "matlab-like" way to do things. Since you're taking each of the items in `Temp.Location`, in the order specified by `indices`, you can rewrite most of your code like this:

```
n = size(indices, 1);
R = zeros(n, 6);


//A(j,1:3)=Temp.Location(indices(j),:); // deleted because never used!
X = Temp.Location(indices(1:n),1); // all the x-values in one columnay list!
Y = Temp.Location(indices(1:n),2);
Z = Temp.Location(indices(1:n),3);
R(:, 1) = X.*X; // term by term squaring
R(:, 2) = Y.*Y;
R(:, 3) = Y;
R(:, 4) = X;
R(:, 5) = X.*Y;
R(:, 6) = 1;
```

That's looking better, but it's still only partway there. I'm going to make a vector the same length as `X` containing only the number $1$, and call this vector `U`, for "unit":

```
n = size(indices, 1);
R = zeros(n, 6);    
X = Temp.Location(indices(1:n),1); // all the x-values in one columnay list!
Y = Temp.Location(indices(1:n),2);
Z = Temp.Location(indices(1:n),3);
U = ones(n, 1); 
...
```

And now I'm going to stick $X, Y,$ and $U$ all into an array $M$, as its columns. I've gotten rid of $A$ because you never used it.

```
R = zeros(n, 6);    
X = Temp.Location(indices(1:n),1); // all the x-values in one columnay list!
Y = Temp.Location(indices(1:n),2);
Z = Temp.Location(indices(1:n),3);
U = ones(n, 1);
M = [X, Y, U]; 
...
```

And finally, I'm going to look at `M'M`. The first entry of this will be the row-vector $X'$ multiplied by the column vector $X$, i.e., it'll be 
$$
x_1^2 + x_2 ^2 + \ldots + x_n^2.
$$
Now that might seem odd, because your code just computes $x_1^2$ and puts it into $R(j, 1)$, and similarly for the others. But if you're doing least-squares fitting right, you need this sum, not the individual values. Your code, later, perhaps sums `R(j, ...)` over all `j` --- it almost certainly *should* do so. So now my (conjectured) version of the right code looks like this:

```
R = zeros(n, 6);    
X = Temp.Location(indices(1:n),1); // all the x-values in one columnay list!
Y = Temp.Location(indices(1:n),2);
Z = Temp.Location(indices(1:n),3);
U = ones(n, 1);
M = [X, Y, U]; 
R = M' * M; // 1,1 entry is X dot X; 1,2 entry is X dot Y; 1, 3 entry
            // is X dot U = sum of all X values, etc.
```

At this point `R` is a symmetric matrix containing all the values you need to complete the least-squares process. Of course, I may have mangled your intentions somewhat --- just looking at your code fragment, it's not clear where you're going with the matrix `R` that you built --- but I've written far more idiomatic and readable matlab code, which will run hugely faster if you ever get around to processing large amounts of data.

Finally, now that we compute `R` only once, that first line, where we allocate `R` as an array full of zeroes ... that can be removed!

N.B.:

In your coefficient computation, you're computing `inv(R'*R) * R' * Z`. That's not going to get you the coefficient you need, because you're squaring a bunch of things that you've already squared. It's also computationally a terrible idea. We seldom solve $Ax = b$ by writing

```
x = inv(A) * b;
```

Instead, you get a huge efficiency improvement if you write

```
x = A \ b;
```

You might want to read the documentation for the backslash operator; it could *substantially* simplify your program.

More important though: I want to suggest that you go back and re-read whatever presentation of least-squares fitting you've seen, until you understand it deeply. Then, and only then, start writing code. Randomly searching through the space of all possible programs for the one that does what you want is almost never a good strategy, even if the random search is clustered "near" some correct code: the search space is simply too large to ever result in a correct answer.

If you think you've already *done* that deep understanding perhaps you can write out here the mathematics that you're trying to emulate with your program.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time  , using your code the results are better but in some cases doesn't fit good. two questions:

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time  , using your code the results are better but in some cases doesn't fit good. two questions: 1) if I want to use weighted matrix too, where is changed? 2) Actually I need some consultation.I have some points (point cloud) I want to extract some geometrical measurments(first and second fundamental form) for each point. The derivative is needed so i first fit a surface around each point, I use least square (polynomial with degree 2) then I calculate them. The results are bad, any tip? any help:)

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called [fit](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html) in matlab which fits a line or surface to given values with a model or regression type. If you simply look. This is an example as I not going to deal with that mess.

```
load franke
sf = fit([x, y],z,'poly23')

 Linear model Poly23:
     sf(x,y) = p00 + p10*x + p01*y + p20*x^2 + p11*x*y + p02*y^2 + p21*x^2*y 
                    + p12*x*y^2 + p03*y^3
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       p00 =       1.118  (0.9149, 1.321)
       p10 =  -0.0002941  (-0.000502, -8.623e-05)
       p01 =       1.533  (0.7032, 2.364)
       p20 =  -1.966e-08  (-7.084e-08, 3.152e-08)
       p11 =   0.0003427  (-0.0001009, 0.0007863)
       p02 =      -6.951  (-8.421, -5.481)
       p21 =   9.563e-08  (6.276e-09, 1.85e-07)
       p12 =  -0.0004401  (-0.0007082, -0.0001721)
       p03 =       4.999  (4.082, 5.917)


plot(sf,[x,y],z)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I used it before but the results aren't good, please read above comment and I am very grateful if you have any tip

Comment: @MR there are more fit options for the function if you actually read the documentation. Also I can't run your code. Consider the smoothing spline option.